# How to embed summernote to a asp.net project with tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tailwind-css, textarea, summernote

I am trying to embed summernote to my project and I am using tailwindcss. I followede the guide to installing summernote to a project but it still does not work.

I added these lines to my _Layout.cshtml under `'<head>` tag:

```
    <link href="/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js"></script>
```

then in my Index.cshtml i tried to initialize summernote using javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#proposed').summernote
    });
</script>
```

then made an id for my `'<textarea>` tag:

```
<div class="mx-2" >
   <textarea id="proposed" class="resize-none w-full h-52 p-2 mb-2 border-2 border-gray-200"></textarea>
</div>
```

but did not work, this was from the guide from youtube, and even though i tried the guide from here

> https://summernote.org/getting-started/#get-summernote

it didn't work since it is for bootstrap.

Is there a way to embed summernote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am not using bootstrap, I found a way to embed summernote to a project in asp.net and it is by using `summernote-lite.js` and `summernote-lite.css`
I have to add this to my libraries.

then add these lines to the `'<head>'` tag in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<link href="summernote-bs5.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="summernote-bs5.js"></script>
```

then manually add this script to your index/view page:

```
$('#proposed').summernote({
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 120,
    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['table', ['table']],
        ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
        ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
    ]
});
```

Using this method it has worked for me while using tailwindcss